# Adverb analogous to "humanly" but having to do with machines or software

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a creative adverb analogous to "humanly" but having to do with machines or software, to put in place of *machinely* in the following example sentence:

> Let's figure out how the software can help us keep this matter as private as humanly, and machinely, possible.

Comment: For software it's obviously *softwarily*.  ;-)

Comment: If you're not trying to be funny you'd just say "as private as possible."  Saying "as private as humanly, and machinely, possible" is done for humorous effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider ***[technologically](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/technologically)***, which means:

> In a way that relates to or involves technology.

It may not be "creative" but it works nicely in your sentence as well as a simpler one:

> - Let's figure out how the software can keep this matter as private as technologically possible.
> - Let's figure out how the software can keep this matter as private as humanly (and technologically) possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking in the same ball park as Silenius.

Although I would go with ***technically***.

> Involving or regarding the technology available.  [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/technically)

Although it might be even less creative, since it's even more common before *possible*.

[image]